# how to add spaces in-between strings at a particular interval?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

So I have a string for instance, "hellomynameissam"

how do I add spaces to every int(x) interval, say if x is 3 then the string becomes

"hel lom yna mei ssa m"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following function to get what you want.

```
def make_interval(string, interval):
    return ' '.join(string[i:i+interval] for i in range(0, len(string), interval))

string = 'hellomynameissam'
print(make_interval(string, 2))
print(make_interval(string, 3))
print(make_interval(string, 4))
```

Output

```
he ll om yn am ei ss am
hel lom yna mei ssa m
hell omyn amei ssam
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
string = "hellomynameissam"
x = 3
out = [string[i:i+x] for i in range(0,len(string),3)]
out = ' '.join(out)
print(out)
```

#### Output

```
hel lom yna mei ssa m
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```py
string="hellomynameissam"
formattedString=""
count=0
for elem in string:
    if (count%3 == 0):
        formattedString= formattedString + " "
    formattedString= formattedString + elem
    count+=1
print(formattedString)
```

**output**

```
hel lom yna mei ssa m
```